# Upcoming events list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

I have a company calendar which has overlays of several other calendars. I need to show a list of the next few upcoming events which incorporates all the overlayed calendars.

So far it seems to be that in order to show the overlayed calendars you must use the 'Calendar' view rather than a list view.

I was hoping to then edit the list using 'Cisar' to make it look presentable but it can't find the calendar list on the page.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Calendar views simply require a Title, Start date/time, and End date/time. with that said you can add overlays to calendar view types. Also be aware that actual calendar lists have the calendar content types so they allow reoccurrences to occur where this isn't possible on non-calendar lists.

Here is more information on Calendar Overlays: https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4CAEBE59-3994-4A94-9322-B31ABB8A5E9A

Also if you add the SharePoint Calendar to a Wiki or Web Part page there is a hidden gem tied to the "Summary" view if you apply it as it will show the calendar items in a list fashion as along with the dates >= Today. (this is just a saved canned view that is historic to older versions of SharePoint.) (Note calendar overlays only show up on calendar type views so those wont show up here.)

Oh and one last thing in overlays I've created sometimes they point to a calendar view that is filtering on a specific column. I'm assuming 'Cisar' might be a choice from a category column in the calendar?

Comment: Thanks for commenting but this doesn't answer the question. Is there a way to display a list of events including the overlayed calendars?

Comment: Not together that I know of. What about having the listing in one web part and then the overlay calendar below it?

Answer (score 0):

Summary view was just what I needed to correct the "Upcoming Events"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is achievable in Events web part in modern pages already. Please refer document from below

1. https://tipsbybits.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-events-webpart/
2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/use-the-events-web-part-5fe4da93-5fa9-4695-b1ee-b0ae4c981909